# Extract date from timestamps of multiple time zones in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame in which I've converted `hour` to `local_hour` based on the `time_zone` column. I now want to extract the date from `local_hour` as `local_date` but I get an error saying `Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`. How can I do this?

```
# Create dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'hour': ['2019-01-01 05:00:00', '2019-01-01 07:00:00', '2019-01-01 08:00:00'],
   'time_zone': ['US/Eastern', 'US/Central', 'US/Mountain']
})

# Convert hour to datetime and localize to UTC
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour']).dt.tz_localize('UTC')

# Get local_hour
df['local_hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['hour'].tz_convert(row['time_zone']), axis=1)

# Try to get local_date from local_hour
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local_hour'].dt.date)
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem only happens when your `local_hour` column contains different timezones. Had everything been in the same timezone, this would have worked:

```
# Work: the whole column in a single timezone
df['local_hour'] = df['hour'].dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
df['local_hour'].dt.date

# Not work: column contains a mix of timezones
df['local_hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['hour'].tz_convert(row['time_zone']), axis=1)
df['local_hour'].dt.date

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

I'd suggest you file an issue with the pandas team. Mean while, you can use `apply` which is essentially a loop:

```
tmp = df['local_hour'].apply(lambda t: pd.Series({
    'date': t.date(),
    'hour': t.hour
}))
df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

```
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True )
df['local_date'] = df['local_date'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Amsterdam')
```

Obviously, the methods can be concatenated, but separated for readibility.

- *utc = True* : Return *UTC DatetimeIndex* which is the needed one to allow the **tz_localize()** method.
- *infer_datetime_format = True* : another useful param which attempts to infer the format of the datetime strings.

Reference in [pandas 0.19](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)