# Cannot convert to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
f26,f27,f28,f29,f30,f31,f32
2018-03-11 03:00:00-04:00,36.0,21,0.00,55,11.5,310
2018-03-11 01:00:00-04:00,36.0,21,0.00,54,12.7,320
2018-03-11 00:00:00-05:00,37.0,20,0.00,50,12.7,310
2018-03-10 23:00:00-05:00,37.0,19,0.00,48,15.0,310
2018-03-10 22:00:00-05:00,38.0,20,0.00,48,16.1,320
```

and when I try to convert `f26` to datetime it fails for some reason.
I suspect this relates to a time zone at the end of a string. But I am not sure how to deal with that. I do not know ahead of time what time format I will receive and I have hundreds of different datasets.

I am doing the following:

```
key = "f26"
df[key] = pd.to_datetime(df[key])
```

I assumed pandas will recognize how to process different datetime formats, but apparently it fails, and I am not sure how to deal with it.

Error: `Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`

So if I add utc=True it works. My current solution is to just try convert it without utc and if I catch exception try utc. 
I am not sure if there is any better solution and how to catch all possible formats without bunch of try-except blocks since I have many tables with many different formats.

Comment: can you add a caption of your error?

Comment: I have run the code successfully and cannot reproduce your error. Please share your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> df[key].apply(lambda x: parse(x))
```

Comment: before trying to convert to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code:

```
input_data = {
    'f26': ['2018-03-10 22:00:00-05:00', '2018-03-10 22:00:00-05:00', '2018-03-10 22:00:00-05:00']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data)
key = "f26"
df[key] = pd.to_datetime(df[key])
```

I was able to successfully run this. Please provide your error message or update your sample code so that we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

```
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True )
df['local_date'] = df['local_date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

Obviously, the methods can be concatenated, but separated for readibility.

- *utc = True* : Return *UTC DatetimeIndex* which is the needed one to allow the **tz_localize()** method.
- *infer_datetime_format = True* : another useful param which attempts to infer the format of the datetime strings.

Reference in [pandas 0.19](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642126/5985898